# In MERN STACK in redux toolkit .Received NaN for the `children` attribute. If this is expected, cast the value to a string

Tags: reactjs, redux, mern

WHEN I REMOVE PRODUCT FROM SHOPPING CART I RECEIVE "Received NaN for the `children` attribute. If this is expected, cast the value to a string"

please also check why this commented line code is not working

//   state.total += action.payload.price * action.payload.quantity;

This is add to cart and remove from cart fucnctions.

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: "cart",
  initialState: {
    products: [],
    quantity: 0,
    total: 0,
  },
  reducers: {
    addProduct: (state, action) => {
      state.quantity += 1;
      state.products.push(action.payload);
    //   state.total += action.payload.price * action.payload.quantity;
    },
    removeProduct: (state, action) => {
        let index = state.products.indexOf(action.payload)
        state.quantity -= action.payload
        state.products.splice(index, 1)
    }
  },
});

export const { addProduct ,removeProduct} = cartSlice.actions;
export default cartSlice.reducer;
```

This is redux store in react application

```
import { configureStore, combineReducers } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import cartReducer from "../features/cartSlice";
import userReducer from "../features/UserSlice";
import {
  persistStore,
  persistReducer,
  FLUSH,
  REHYDRATE,
  PAUSE,
  PERSIST,
  PURGE,
  REGISTER,
} from "redux-persist";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";

const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  version: 1,
  storage,
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({ user: userReducer, cart: cartReducer });

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: {
        ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
      },
    }),
});

export let persistor = persistStore(store);
```

Comment: Either `action.payload.price` or `action.payload.quantity` is `null` or `undefined`. Please show how do you call `addProduct`

Comment: const addtocart=()=>{

  disaptch(addProduct())

}

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `addProduct` should take an argument

Comment: yes action.payload.quantity is null .How i can solve it

Comment: Call `addProduct` with an argument being the data you want to pass e.g. `{ price: 3, quantity: 7 }`

Comment: bro i can send you code can you help me in this regard

Comment: please.Thi is my first project and important one too

Comment: `const addtocart=()=>{ disaptch(addProduct({ price: 1, quantity: 2 })) }`

Comment: it didnt sove the problem

Comment: Also `dispatch` not `disaptch`

Comment: This was just a variable

Answer (score 0):

The brother who commented above was write .I just pass `cart quantity` in `const addtocart=()=>{ disaptch(addProduct(product) }` and it worked

Here `product` is the quantity of produts in cart which is as follow

```
 const product = useSelector((state) => state.cart.quantity)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).